# how can I use twig blocks in my twig templates?

Tags: twig

I have a problem, I am using twig templates and am trying to use blocks to separate my code but I have the following error:

```
Twig_Error_Loader: Template "index.html.twig" is not defined in "requestchange/main.twig" at line 1
```

`index.html.twig` is my main template layout

I have added in: `{% block content %}{% endblock %}`

then in my main.twig , I am extending the index.html.twig file and then putting my content within another `{% block content %}{% endblock %}`

Can someone please help me here?

Comment: Where did you place `index.html.twig`? What is your `extends`?

Comment: Post code from `index.html.twig` and `main.twig`.

Answer (score 1):

You should understand how [Template Inheritance](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#template-inheritance) works in Twig.

Here is simple example:

`default.twig` as a default layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

`index.twig` as a home page

```
{% extends 'default.twig' %}

{% block title %}Home page{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

And be attentive with path that you point in the `extends` tag.